# Python error while installing NodeJS on OpenSuse 12.3

Tags: node.js, npm, opensuse, etherpad

I am trying to install NodeJS on OpenSuse 12.3 from source. I need it in order to get Etherpad-Lite working.
Node.JS version 0.8.0
When trying to install by it by ./configure then make and then make install I get the following error code:

```
{ 'target_defaults': { 'cflags': [],
'default_configuration': 'Release',
'defines': [],
'include_dirs': [],
'libraries': []},
'variables': { 'host_arch': 'ia32',
'node_install_npm': 'true',
'node_install_waf': 'true',
'node_prefix': '',
'node_shared_openssl': 'false',
'node_shared_v8': 'false',
'node_shared_zlib': 'false',
'node_use_dtrace': 'false',
'node_use_etw': 'false',
'node_use_openssl': 'true',
'strict_aliasing': 'true',
'target_arch': 'ia32',
'v8_use_snapshot': 'true'}}
creating ./home/etherpad/node-v0.8.0/config.gypi
creating ./home/etherpad/node-v0.8.0/config.mk
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./home/etherpad/node-v0.8.0/configure", line 401, in 
subprocess.call(['tools/gyp_node', '-f', 'make'])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

If I am using the latest version of NodeJS I get another error:

```
/usr/bin/python: can't open file 'tools/gyp_node': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
{ 'target_defaults': { 'cflags': [],
'default_configuration': 'Release',
'defines': [],
'include_dirs': [],
'libraries': []},
'variables': { 'clang': 0,
'gcc_version': 47,
'host_arch': 'ia32',
'node_install_npm': 'true',
'node_prefix': '',
'node_shared_cares': 'false',
'node_shared_http_parser': 'false',
'node_shared_libuv': 'false',
'node_shared_openssl': 'false',
'node_shared_v8': 'false',
'node_shared_zlib': 'false',
'node_tag': '',
'node_unsafe_optimizations': 0,
'node_use_dtrace': 'false',
'node_use_etw': 'false',
'node_use_openssl': 'true',
'node_use_perfctr': 'false',
'node_use_systemtap': 'false',
'python': '/usr/bin/python',
'target_arch': 'ia32',
'v8_enable_gdbjit': 0,
'v8_no_strict_aliasing': 1,
'v8_use_snapshot': 'true'}}
creating ./home/etherpad/node-v0.10.12/config.gypi
creating ./home/etherpad/node-v0.10.12/config.mk
make: Nothing to be done for `/home/etherpad/node-v0.10.12'.
make: *** No rule to make target `install'. Stop.
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Is there a specific reason for not using the opensuse package manager? https://build.opensuse.org/package/show?package=nodejs&project=devel%3Alanguages%3Anodejs

Comment: I tried installing it from the package manager which works but there are many npm errors with etherpad so I thought installing everything from source would be the easiest.

Comment: I'm taking a shot in the dark here but perhaps you're forgetting `sudo make install`? If this was the problem I'd expect a permission denied-related error but it's possible I suppose.

Comment: I am using sudo make install and I am running every comment as root if this was your question.

Comment: why are you trying to install nodejs from source? I've installed it from repository, and no problems at all..

Answer (score 0):

(1) Your post is dated 1 Jul 2013 and back then, the latest stable version of nodejs was v0.10.12, which was introduced on 19 Jun 2013. As of today, 13 Mar 2014, the latest stable source code version of node js v0.10.26 As of today, your source code version of nodejs is definitely not the latest.

(2) In the nodejs directory that I extracted from my downloaded nodejs tarball, there is a first-level *tools* directory

```
[root@new-host node-v0.10.26]# pwd
/usr/src/node-v0.10.26
[root@new-host node-v0.10.26]# ls -F
AUTHORS      ChangeLog    config.mk        deps/  LICENSE   node.gyp   src/    vcbuild.bat
benchmark/   common.gypi  configure*       doc/   Makefile  out/       test/
BSDmakefile  config.gypi  CONTRIBUTING.md  lib/   node@     README.md  tools/
```

And within that *tools/* directory, there is supposed to be a file called *gyp_node*

```
[root@new-host node-v0.10.26]# ls tools/gyp_*
tools/gyp_node.py
```

Do you see that file *tools/gyp-node.py* in my listing of node-v0.10.26 above? Good. That's what the Makefile refers to as "tools/gyp_node"  You've got an error message that is jumping at you right from the first line:

```
/usr/bin/python: can't open file 'tools/gyp_node': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

and the meaning of that error message is self-evident.

Let's summarize: as of today, 13 Mar 2014, you are NOT working with the latest version of nodejs and the version of nodejs that you are working with is missing the file *tools/gyp_node.py* Your problem is bizarro since v0.10.12 is supposed to be a stable version of nodejs, which means that the file *gyp_node.py* should have been present in your *tools/* directory.

Comment: I build v0.10.27 , this is still happened in a build-tree when I separate the build with another source-tree dir., while directly build under the source-tree is OK!